# scrollbar box containing UL list

Tags: css

i have this template code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    //submit new messages when the user hits enter if the message isnt blank

    now.receiveMessage = function(name, message, messagetime){
      $("#messages").append(
                    '<li class="message"><div class="sent"><a href="${path}"><img src="${gravatar}" alt="name" width="24px" height="24px" /></a><div class="display-name">'+messagetime+'<div class="body">'+ message +'</div></div></div></li>');
      }
      $("#text-input").keypress(function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode != 13 /* Return */) return;
           now.distributeMessage($("#text-input").val());
          $("#text-input").attr("value", ""); // clear the entry field.
        });
      $("#send-button").click(function(){
        now.distributeMessage($("#text-input").val());
      $("#text-input").val("");
      });
    now.name = "${user}";
  });
</script>

    <div id="chat_window">
        <div id="chat_title"><h2>Simple Chat</h2></div>
        <div id="chat_container" style="display: block">
            <div id="chat">
                <ul id="messages">
                    <li class="message notice" id="no_one_there">
                        Fix me, if there are no users!
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="chat-form">
            <input type="text" id="text-input" />
    <input type="button" value="Send" id="send-button" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this CSS

```
div#chat {
width:100%;
height:100px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

basically it is a chat window, but i am have a block in that i can't seem to figure out how to align the

elements so that the scrollbar of the #chat div is always at the bottom of the box. similar to the google chat window, where you need to scroll up to see old messages.

thanks

Comment: i tried your suggestions, but none seem to work. why have you added it twice?

Comment: there is a javascript block with <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#chat").scrollTo('100%');
    </script> at the bottom plus $("#chat").attr({ scrollTop: $("#chat").attr("scrollHeight") }); to the nowjs $("#send-button").click(function(

Comment: sorry, this produces Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'scrollTo'

Comment: Now here it is your working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to

```
now.receiveMessage = function (name, message, messagetime) {
                $("#messages").append(  '<li class="message"><div class="sent"><a href="/"><img width="24px" alt="name" height="24px"></a><div class="display-name">' + messagetime + '<div class="body">' + message + '</div></div></div></li>');
document.getElementById("chat").scrollTop = document.getElementById("chat").scrollHeight;
}
```

And complete code is here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Welcome - Zeitgeist Movement Global Connect</title>
  <base href="http://zmgc.net/">
  <!-- Meta -->
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta lang="en" name="description" content="One back-office to bring them all and in the darkness bind them, in an anarchically scalable information system.">
  <!-- Canonical URL for search engines -->
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://zmgc.net/">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/core/css/yui/cssreset/reset-min.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/core/css/yui/cssgrids/grids-min.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/core/css/core.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/core/css/flags-sprite.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/core/css/widgets.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/js_calendar/calendar-aruni.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/wiki/style.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/phoenix/style.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="ui/phoenix/jquery/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/core/css/jPlayer/jplayer.pink.flag.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/core/css/jPlayer/zen.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/ui/core/css/jPlayer/ui.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/style/;download" type="text/css">
  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script src="/ui/core/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/ui/core/js/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/ui/core/js/raphaeljs/raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/ui/core/js/world.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/ui/js_calendar/jquery.dynDateTime.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/ui/js_calendar/lang/calendar-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="ui/phoenix/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/ui/core/js/jPlayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/ui/core/js/jPlayer/add-on/jplayer.playlist.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/ui/core/js/jquery/add-on/jquery.rotate.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/ui/core/js/tab.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/ui/core/js/zplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Icon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/ui/phoenix/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
  <!-- Add YUI3 grids-->
  <div id="hd" class="yui3-g">
      <div id="logo" class="yui3-u-1-12"><!-- logo width: 4.1666%-->
        <h1 title="Welcome - Zeitgeist Movement Global Connect">
          <a href="/" title="Welcome - Zeitgeist Movement Global Connect">Zeitgeist Movement Global Connect</a>
        </h1>
      </div> <!-- /logo-->
      <div class="yui3-u-11-12"><!-- width: 95.8333%-->
        <div class="yui3-g">
          <div id="menu" class="yui3-u-1-2"><!-- menu width: 66.6666%-->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/calendar">Calendar</a></li>
              <li><a href="/forums">Forums</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/;more">More »</a></li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
          <div id="user-menu" class="yui3-u-1-2"><!--  width: 33.33333%-->
                        <ul>

                        <li><a href="/./;login" class="login" title="Login">Login</a></li>


                      <li><a href="/;contact" class="contact" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/help" class="help" title="Help">Help</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/;advanced_search" class="advanced-search" title="Advanced Search">Advanced Search</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <form action=";browse_content" method="get">
                        <div class="search placeholder-field">
                          <input name="search_text" type="text">
                          <input value="Search" class="button" type="submit">
                        </div>
                      </form>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- /yui3-g  search and user profile-->
        </div>
  </div><!-- /yui3-g id="hd"-->




  <div id="language">

    <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="lang-en" href="http://zmgc.net/?language=en" class="selected" title="English">English</a>
    </li><li>
      <a href="http://zmgc.net/?language=fr" id="lang-fr" title="Français">Français</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>



  <!-- Bread crumbs -->
  <div>
      <label>



  <!-- Location & Views-->
  <div id="location">
    <div id="breadcrumbs">
      location »  <span><a href="/" title="Zeitgeist Movement Global Connect">Zeitgeist Movement Global Conn…</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="submenu">
    <span class="menu active">
      <a href="/./;view">Welcome</a>
      |
    </span><span class="menu ">
      <a href="/./;browse_content">Browse Content</a>
      |
    </span><span class="menu ">
      <a href="/./;preview_content">Preview Content</a>
      |
    </span><span class="menu ">
      <a href="/./;links">Links</a>
      |
    </span><span class="menu ">
      <a href="/./;backlinks">Backlinks</a>
      |
    </span><span class="menu ">
      <a href="/./;control_panel">Advanced</a>

    </span>
  </div>

</label>
  </div><!-- /location-->
  <!-- /Bread crumbs -->
  <div id="page">

  <!-- body -->
    <div class="yui-g">
    <!-- all other templates go within this block -->




<div class="yui3-g"><!-- content -->
  <div class="yui3-u-1-2"><!-- welcome block 40%-->
    <div class="welcome">
      <h1>Welcome  to the Zeitgeist Movement portal!</h1>
      <p>
        Founded in 2008, The Zeitgeist Movement is a Sustainability Advocacy Organization which conducts community based activism and awareness actions through a network of Global/Regional Chapters, Project Teams, Annual Events, Media and Charity Work.</p>
    </div> <!-- / welcome block 40%-->
    <!-- latest activities-->
    <div class="box-holder">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="holder">
          <div class="frame">
            <div class="box-content">
              <h3>
                <span>All the latest activities ...</span>
              </h3>
              <ul class="supports-list">
                <li class="">
                  <img src="/ui/core/resources/ico-wrote-petition.gif" alt="wrote-petition">                                    
                  <p>
                    <strong>Katia</strong> signed up to help with the Z-Day Festival: London</p>
                    <a href="#" title="Sign up to help">Sign up to help</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="">
                    <img src="/ui/core/resources/ico-donate.gif" alt="wrote-petition">                                    
                    <p>
                      <strong>Luisa</strong> donated 5 € towards the Occupy London Fund </p>
                      <a href="#/" title="Wish to donate...">Wish to donate...</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="last">
                      <img src="/ui/core/resources/ico-wrote-petition.gif" alt="wrote-petition">                                    
                      <p>
                        <strong>Patricia</strong> signed up to help with the Z-Day Festival: London</p>
                        <a href="#/" title="Sign up to help">Sign up to help</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div> <!-- /box-content-->
                </div> <!-- /frame-->
              </div> <!-- /holder-->
            </div> <!-- /box-->
          </div> <!-- /box-holder-->
          <!-- /latest activities-->
    <!-- tabs-->



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
          $('#container-1').tabs();
          $("#container-2 > ul").tabs({ 
              navClass: "ui-tabs-sub-nav",
              selectedClass: 'ui-tabs-sub-selected',
              unselectClass: 'ui-tabs-sub-unselect',
              disabledClass: 'ui-tabs-sub-disabled',
              panelClass: 'ui-tabs-sub-panel',
              loadingClass: 'ui-tabs-sub-loading'
            });
        });

    </script>
    <div id="container-1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#actions"><span>Actions</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#news"><span>News</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#events"><span>Events</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#chapters"><span>Chapters</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#forums"><span>Forums</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="actions">
        {actions}
                <ul>
            <li><a href="#actions"><span>Actions</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#news"><span>News</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#events"><span>Events</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#chapters"><span>Chapters</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#forums"><span>Forums</span></a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="news">
        {news}
      </div>
      <div id="events">
        {events}
      </div>
      <div id="chapters">
        <div id="container-2">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#chapter-1"><span>Africa</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#chapter-2"><span>Americas</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#chapter-3"><span>Asia</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#chapter-4"><span>Europe</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          <div id="chapter-1">
              Africa
          </div>
          <div id="chapter-2">
              Americas
          </div>
          <div id="chapter-3">
              Asia
          </div>
          <div id="chapter-4">
              Europe
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="forums">
        {forums}
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- /tabs-->
  </div><!-- /welcome block 40%-->
  <div class="yui3-u-1-4 media"><!-- movies, radio and events block 40%-->



        <!-- player widget-->
        <input value="" id="tmp_duration" type="hidden">
        <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer">
          <img id="jp_poster_0">
        </div>
        <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-video">
          <div class="jp-video-play">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-video-play-icon" tabindex="1">play</a>
          </div>
          <div class="jp-type-playlist">
            <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
                <div class="jp-progress">
                  <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                    <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id="panel"><!-- /id="panel" -->
                <div class="jp-current-time">00:05</div>
                <div class="jp-duration">00:33</div>
                <div class="jp-title"><ul><li>Item Title</li></ul>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-controls-holder"> <!-- class="jp-controls-holder" -->
                  <ul class="jp-controls">
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-previous" tabindex="1">previous</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" style="display: block;" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" style="display: none;" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-next" tabindex="1">next</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute" style="display: none;">unmute</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                    <div class="jp-volume-bar-value" style="width: 80%; "></div>
                  </div>
                </div> <!-- /class="jp-controls-holder" -->
              </div> <!-- /id="panel" -->
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn-slide">Slide bar</a>
            <div id="tab" class="tabsBlock">
              <ul class="tabs">
                <li><a index="1" href="#tabs-1" title="tabs-1">Video</a></li>
                <li><a index="2" href="#tabs-2" title="tabs-2">Audio</a></li>
                <li><a index="3" href="#tabs-3" title="tabs-3">Films</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div index="1" class="jp-playlist">
                <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-item default">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="list">
                      <a href="javascript:;" title="unselect" m4v="http://www.archive.org/download/Zeitgeist.Addendum/Zeitgeist.Addendum_512kb.mp4" ogv="http://www.archive.org/download/Zeitgeist.Addendum/Zeitgeist.Addendum.ogv" poster="http://www.archive.org/download/Zeitgeist.Addendum/Zeitgeist.Addendum.thumbs/Zeitgeist.Addendum_000060.jpg" class="track">
                      Zeitgeist: Addendum (2008)</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div index="2" class="jp-playlist" style="display: none;">
                <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-item" style="display: none;">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="list"><a mp="http://www.archive.org/download/TzmDevPhoenixMeeting12-04-2011/ts3_recording_11_12155E7A5.mp3" href="javascript:;" title="unselect" poster="/ui/core/resources/jplayer-default0.jpg" class="track" oga="http://www.archive.org/download/TzmDevPhoenixMeeting12-04-2011/ts3_recording_11_12155E7A5.ogg">TZM Dev Phoenix Meeting 12-04-2011</a></li>
                    <li class="list"><a mp="http://www.archive.org/download/TzmDevPhoenixMeeting12-11-2011/Tzm-dev-phx12-11-11.mp3" href="javascript:;" title="unselect" poster="/ui/core/resources/jplayer-default0.jpg" class="track" oga="http://www.archive.org/download/TzmDevPhoenixMeeting12-11-2011/Tzm-dev-phx12-11-11.ogg">TZM Dev Phoenix Meeting 12-11-2011</a></li>
                    <li class="list"><a mp="http://www.archive.org/download/TzmDevPhoenixMeeting01-01-2012/ts3_recording_12_01.mp3" href="javascript:;" title="unselect" poster="/ui/core/resources/jplayer-default0.jpg" class="track" oga="http://www.archive.org/download/TzmDevPhoenixMeeting01-01-2012/ts3_recording_12_01.ogg">TZM Dev Phoenix Meeting 01-01-2012</a></li> 
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>    
              <div index="3" class="jp-playlist" style="display: none;">    
                <div id="tabs-3" class="tab-item" style="display: none;">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="list"><a href="javascript:;" title="unselect" m4v="http://www.archive.org/download/ZeitgeistTheMovie/Zeitgeist_512kb.mp4" ogv="http://www.archive.org/download/ZeitgeistTheMovie/Zeitgeist.ogv" poster="http://www.archive.org/download/ZeitgeistTheMovie/Zeitgeist.gif" class="track">Zeitgeist</a></li>
                    <li class="list">
                      <a href="javascript:;" title="unselect" m4v="http://www.archive.org/download/Zeitgeist.Addendum/Zeitgeist.Addendum_512kb.mp4" ogv="http://www.archive.org/download/Zeitgeist.Addendum/Zeitgeist.Addendum.ogv" poster="http://www.archive.org/download/Zeitgeist.Addendum/Zeitgeist.Addendum.thumbs/Zeitgeist.Addendum_000060.jpg" class="track">
                      Zeitgeist: Addendum (2008)</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /player widget-->




    <div class="yui3-g">
      <div class="yui3-u-1-3" id="watch-related-container">
         <!--  <iframe width="300px"height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QYLLFpNn4lM" frameborder="0"></iframe> -->
             <ul id="watch-related" class="video-list">
               <!-- video-list-item -->
               <li class="video-list-item">
                 <a href="videos/video-item" class="video-list-item-link">
                   <span class="ux-thumb-wrap contains-addto">
                     <span class="video-thumb">
                       <span class="clip">
                         <img src="/ui/core/resources/jplayer-default1.jpg" alt="clip-title">
                         <span class="uix-button-content">
                           <span class="addto-label">Add to</span>
                         </span>
                       </span><!-- /clip-->
                       <span class="video-time">14:30</span>
                       <button class="addto-button video-actions" type="button">
                         <img src="/ui/core/resources/pixel.gif" class="uix-addto-button">
                       </button>
                       <span dir="ltr" class="title" title="Video Title">Video Title</span>
                       <span class="stat">
                         by <span dir="ltr" class="yt-user-name ">username</span>
                       </span><!-- /stat-->
                     </span><!-- /video-thumb-->
                   </span><!-- /ux-thumb-wrap contains-addto-->
                 </a>
               </li>
               <!-- /video-list-item -->
             </ul><!-- /watch-related .video-list-->
         </div><!-- /watch-related-container-->
      <div class="yui3-u-2-3">
        <img src="../../ui/icons/48x48/skin.png" border="0">

        events table
      </div><!-- /yui3-u-2-3-->
    </div><!-- /yui3-g-->
  </div><!-- /movies, radio and events block 40%-->
  <div class="yui3-u-1-4 chat"><!-- right side bar 20%-->
    <!-- START DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FTheZeitgeistMovement&amp;width=290&amp;height=290&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;appId=119920878043766" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:290px; height:290px;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <!-- <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
    <fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/zeitgeist" width="300" connections="15"></fb:like-box> 
     END DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
    <div class="listings items">
    <h3>Follow us on...</h3>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="/ui/core/resources/facebook.png" width="48" height="48" border="0"></a>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/Zeitgeist" target="_blank"><img src="/ui/core/resources/twitter.png" width="48" height="48" border="0"></a>
    <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheZeitgeistMovement" target="_blank"><img src="/ui/core/resources/rss_icon_48.jpg" width="48" height="48" border="0"></a>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/TZMOfficialChannel" target="_blank"><img src="/ui/core/resources/youtube.png" width="48" height="48" border="0"></a> 
    </div> <!-- END DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
    <!-- I LIKE IT -->
    <div class="thumb-rating">
        <form method="post" action="you-know-you-like-it" class="disabled">
            <span class="thumbs-up">
                <input alt="Please log in to rate this product" value="Like" disabled="disabled" name="lovinit" class="allowMultiSubmit like-button" type="submit"></span>
            <span class="thumbs-down">
                <input value="Ugh" disabled="disabled" name="hatedit" class="allowMultiSubmit dislike-button" type="submit"></span>
        </form>
        <div class="like-summary">
            <span class="total-thumbs-up">
                <span class="tally-total">0</span> likes,
            </span>
            <span class="total-thumbs-down">
                <span class="tally-total">0</span> dislikes
            </span>

        </div>
        <div class="discreet login-to-rate">
            <a href="/;login" class="link-overlay">Log in</a> to rate.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
    <ul>
        <li class="forum"><a href="/forum">Forum</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /I LIKE IT -->

    <script src="http://zmgc.net:29080/nowjs/now.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //submit new messages when the user hits enter if the message isnt blank

            now.receiveMessage = function (name, message, messagetime) {
                $("#messages").append(
                        '<li class="message"><div class="sent"><a href="/"><img width="24px" alt="name" height="24px"></a><div class="display-name">' + messagetime + '<div class="body">' + message + '</div></div></div></li>');
                document.getElementById("chat").scrollTop = document.getElementById("chat").scrollHeight;
            }
            $("#text-input").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode != 13 /* Return */) return;
                now.distributeMessage($("#text-input").val());
                $("#text-input").attr("value", ""); // clear the entry field.
            });
            $("#send-button").click(function () {
                now.distributeMessage($("#text-input").val());
                $("#text-input").val("");
            });

            now.name = "";

        });

    </script>

        <div id="chat_window">
            <div id="chat_title"><h2>Simple Chat</h2></div>
            <div id="chat_container" style="display: block">
                <div id="chat">
                    <ul id="messages">
                        <li class="message notice" id="no_one_there">
                            Fix me, if there are no users!
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="chat-form">
                <input id="text-input" type="text">
        <input value="Send" id="send-button" type="button">
            </div>
        </div>

  <ul id="status">
      <li><a href="#" id="usersLink">5 users</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="usersLink">uptime: <span id="uptime">?</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="usersLink">memory: <span id="rss">?</span>mb RSS</a></li>
    </ul>




  </div><!-- /right side bar 20%-->
</div><!-- /content -->


    <!-- /all other templates go within this block -->
    </div>
  <!-- /body -->
</div><!-- /YUI3 grids-->
</div> <!-- /end of wrap-->
<div id="footer">
    <div class="yui3-g" id="upper-footer"><!-- upper-footer -->



  <div class="yui3-u-3-4 upper_footer">
      <h4 id="tzm">Zeigeist Links</h4>
      <ul class="footer_nav">
        <h4>Zeigeist</h4>
        <li>
          <a href="/;about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/blog">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/;contact">Contact &amp; Support</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/training">Training</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Site Status</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="footer_nav">
        <h4>Tools</h4>
        <li>
          <a href="/;create">Chapter Generator</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Activies Board</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="footer_nav">
        <h4>Documentation</h4>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Chapter Sites</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Developers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="footer_nav">
        <h4>External Links</h4>
        <li>
          <a href="#">News</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Media</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div><!-- /yui3-u-3-4 -->
  <div id="worldmap" class="yui3-u-1-4"></div>


    </div><!-- /upper-footer -->
    <div id="lower-footer">
          <ul>
            <li class="space">
              <h1 title="Welcome - Zeitgeist Movement Global Connect">
                <a href="/" title="Welcome - Zeitgeist Movement Global Connect">
                  striving for a better future since 2008</a>
                </h1>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/;about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="/;more">More</a></li>

              <li><a href="/;login_form">(not logged in)</a></li>


          </ul>
    </div><!-- /lower-footer -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
<!--[if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am not using jQuery, i am using http://nowjs.com/examples/hw as my chat client and when i add the jQuery block it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I see you want to do this CSS only, well, you can, but it has its downsides. Lets start with a simple example of how it can be done using html/css.

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/hkTaZ/

This doesn't use JS.

**Edit:**

For the chat box in the link you provided, you will need to add the following styles:

```
#chat {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#messages {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

But, when you want to scroll to the top you will have to implement something to be able to scroll to the top. That would require some JS to manipulate the bottom attribute of content.

The library you're pointing to **DOES** use jQuery though it's not very apparent so you can use jQuery to make this functionality.

Though seeing you already use JS it would be easier to scroll to the bottom each time a message is appended to the chat as @jams answer does.

**Edit:**

Seeing your current implementation uses javascript I suggest you take @jams suggestion to scroll to the bottom each time a message is added to the `#messages` list.

Comment: i still can't get it to work ;( here is the site, http://zmgc.net/ the chat window is on the bottom right.

Comment: @khinester see the updated answer on your specific implementation

Comment: thanks for all your help, i changed it so that the messages are prepend rather then appended to the UL list.

Comment: Please accept they answer you deemed most helpfull, and really, in my opinion that was @jams I just needed more space to explain some stuff.